# Ticketsystem: sql tables

Tags: mysql, sql

I am not really that good in creating MySQL tables.

I want to create a small ticket system, where the user can apply the following information:

- Ticket username
- Ticket email
- Question

[image: Snapshot]

After this was submitted, I want the information to be stored in an database table.

Now the supporter and the user should be able to add comments to this ticket.

I tried to create the tables, but I am a little worried if it would work this way:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `Tickets` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `username` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `email` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `ticket_id` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  `ticket_question` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `ticket_status` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `ticket_creation_date` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
  PRIMARY KEY (`ticket_id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `username` (`username`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=203 ;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `Conversation` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `ticket_id` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  `ticket_comment` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `ticket_latest_reply` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
  PRIMARY KEY (`ticket_id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `username` (`username`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=203 ;
```

Could anyone have a look at this or correct me?

Comment: You should have another table for each comment. Something like "Conversation_Comment"

Comment: To save all the comments in there related to a ticket_id? In case yes, then i planned to store them in the Conversation table

Comment: If you mean that your second table will contain many records for each record in `tickets` then it's ok for a draft (afterwards you'll need more tables). But remove unique key username from second table and add some info about user in it. Actually you might need whole new user table - which will be linked to ticket table and comment\conversation table.

Comment: That's true, i would like to store more comments to an ticket conversation.

Comment: See my answer below ;)

Comment: so yes, you may start with this structure (removing errors from sql first) and when later you'll see that you need another table or field (users, or some additinal info f.e. when ticket was edited) you can just add it. Of course good practice is to design all tables from the beginning but it's perfectly ok to add tables during development too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you'd like to be able to add more than one comment to a ticket. In the way you are setting up your tables this isn't possible, 'cause you are setting `ticket_id`as primary key.

You should set `id` in the `ConversationTable` as pirmary key and `ticket_id` as a foreign key to the `Ticket` tables `ticket_id`, because you can have multiple comments to one ticket

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `Tickets` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `username` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `email` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `ticket_id` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  `ticket_question` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `ticket_status` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `ticket_creation_date` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ticket_id`),
  UNIQUE KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `username` (`username`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `Conversation` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `ticket_id` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  `ticket_comments` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `ticket_latest_reply` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_tickets` FOREIGN KEY (`ticket_id`) REFERENCES `Tickets`(`ticket_id`)  ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Attention: If you now delete a ticket_id in your Ticket-table, this will delete all comments related to this ticket (ON DELETE CASCADE)

In this case each comment is stored in this table.

If you want the conversation as a single conversation you need an additional table holding all comments and link the comments in the `Conversation` table by ID like doing it with `ticket_comment` you did above.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `Tickets` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `username` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `email` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `ticket_id` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  `ticket_question` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `ticket_status` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `ticket_creation_date` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ticket_id`),
  UNIQUE KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY (`username`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `Conversation` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `ticket_id` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  `comment_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `ticket_latest_reply` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY (`ticket_id`, `comment_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `Comments` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `comment` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `comment_last_update` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

And maybe think about setting `ticket_id` as primary key in `Tickets`. When it is unique, you also can use it as primary key.

Comment: Getting the following error: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '(`ticket_id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `username` (`username`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT C' at line 9

Comment: So the table called Tickets would store the ticket informations after the user created it.
The Conversation table would store the infos between Tickets table and Comments,
The Comments table would store every comment from every ticket right?

Comment: Correct :) Hope that helps

Comment: It does help me alot, just one more question, Where's the connection between Conversation and Comments? Like how does the Comment know its bound to this specific conversation? The connection between Tickets and Conversation would be ticket_id but what is it between Conversation - Comments

Comment: Conversation - Comments are bound by `comment_id`in `Conversation` table

Answer (score 1):

Working code:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `Tickets` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `username` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `email` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `ticket_id` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  `ticket_question` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `ticket_status` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  `ticket_creation_date` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY (`username`, `ticket_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=203 ;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `Conversation` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `ticket_id` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  `ticket_comments` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `ticket_latest_reply` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=203 ;
```

SqlFiddle: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/36aca1

Things that were wrong:

- The key with auto increment should be the primary key.
- As you want `ticket_id` to be unique, define it as unique key.
- There was `,` missig after `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` in first query.
- There is no username column, so you cannot define it as unique in the 2nd query.
- And this query is in `MySql` and not in `sql`. Put appropriate tags to your question from next time.

Comment: This is working code, of course. But with this setup it is not possible to have more than one comment for eacht `ticket_id`, beacuse the `ticket_id` in the `Conversation` table is unique

Comment: Ohh my bad. I just solved the errors. Did not look for the functionality. Thanks

Comment: Your'e welcome. You solved those problems I've overlooked ;)